# Performance of function which connects to database

Tags: php, sql, performance

I have a function to check wether a function/module is disabled by an admin or not.

**The function looks like this (in functions.php):**

```
function function_enabled($function_module) {
    include("dbconnect.php");
    if ($function_module == "changelogs" OR $function_module == "news" OR $function_module == "calendar" OR $function_module == "groups" OR $function_module == "settings" OR $function_module == "eat" OR $function_module == "weather" OR $function_module == "usertext" OR $function_module == "login") {
        $sql = $db->query("SELECT enabled FROM functions WHERE function_name = '$function_module'");
        $row = $sql->fetch_object();
        $return = $row->enabled;
        return $return;
    }
}
```

**And this is how I use the function (in any other php file):**

```
include("functions.php");
if(function_enabled("weather") == 1) {
    //do the weather stuff here
} else {
    echo"Function disabled";
}
```

Now my question: How is the performance of this function? Can this cause relative high performance hits? Is there a better/faster way to check wether a function is enabled or not or is this script okay?

**UPDATE 1**

Now, I combined these multiple queries into one so that all values are in an array.

```
function compare_id($a, $b) {
    if ($a['id'] == $b['id']) return 0;
    return ($a['id'] < $b['id']) ? -1 : 1;
}   

$sql = $db->query("SELECT function_name, enabled, id FROM functions");

$function_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $function_array[] = $row;
}
usort($function_array, compare_id);

if($function_array[0]['enabled'] == 1) {
    echo"changelogs enabled<br>";
} else {
    echo"changelogs disabled<br>";
}

if($function_array[2]['enabled'] == 1) {
    echo"calendar enabled<br>";
} else {
    echo"calendar disabled<br>";
}

if($function_array[7]['enabled'] == 1) {
    echo"usertext enabled<br>";
} else {
    echo"usertext disabled<br>";
}

if($function_array[8]['enabled'] == 1) {
    echo"login enabled<br>";
} else {
    echo"login disabled<br>";
}

if($function_array[4]['enabled'] == 1) {
    echo"settings enabled<br>";
} else {
    echo"settings disabled<br>";
}
```

Is this method faster?

Comment: use an object instead of functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks OK. Is it giving you issues? There could be performance issues in the DB query from the table or index.

Generally you shouldn't build for performance from the start. Rather build something that functions, then go back an optmise where the choke points are. There are high load webservices which use simple frameworks (Ruby on Rails, Laravel) They only have to optimise 2-5% of the code where the load is. When you know where the choke points are and why its choking you can make an educated choice on how to optmise. Should it be optimised, or should I rewite this in another language.

Does your functions table change fequently? If not you could possibly export it to file. Then PHP could read it once and store it in Memory as an array. Referencing an array would be a lot faster `functions['weather'] == 1` with no DB throughput issues.

Comment: Nope, the table doesn't change very ofen. I understand your idea but how can I store this array in the memory and if an admin disabled a function, php should get the new array.

Comment: It should be fine in DB as you have it. Unless its causing issues now?

Comment: I don't know wether it is causing issues. But I thought it could hit performance if there are 6 sql queries on the start-page (because I have 6 modules on the start-page). Maybe I can check the performance with `microtime`

Comment: Ok I see your concern. And probably yes there is a performance hit from the 6 queries. This is a MySQL concern not so much with PHP. Either use less queries, combine the ones you can etc. Or if you use Innodb table you can set the buffer pool config to the size of the DB, allowing MySQL to cache everything.

Comment: I have the idea to combine these 6 queries into one and then save all data in an array. Would be this solution better for the performance?

Comment: Yeah if you can somehow combine the queries that 'should' help. In most cases it should. If the query becomes too large with lots of joins and the DB tables are massive (millions of rows) it might slow it down.

Comment: I updated my first post with the "one query and all into one array"-method. Is that faster?

Comment: Honestly I can't tell you. It depends on the configuration of the DB and  what the queries are. Most likely it is faster, but you'd have to benchmark the application before and after to confirm a speed increase.

Comment: Its faster with the array-solution. I checked this with microtime :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function function_enabled($function_module) {
    $_FUNCTION_MODULE = array ("changelogs", "news", "calendar", "groups", "settings", "eat", "weather", "usertext", "login");
    require_once ("dbconnect.php");
    if (in_array($function_module, $_FUNCTION_MODULE) {
        $query      = $db->query("SELECT enabled FROM functions WHERE function_name = '$function_module'");
        $row            = $query->fetch_object();
        $isEnabled  = $row->enabled;
        return $isEnabled;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```